# Limit of function without Taylor

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I have found one interesting task: find the 
following limit without using Taylor series

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x-\sqrt{x-1}\log\left(x^2+e^{\sqrt x}\right)\right)=\frac 12$$
But don’t have any idea how to solve it. Can somebody give a hint?  I have already tested some actions for using L'Hospital's rule, but without success

Comment: Where did you find this? What is your question? If you show your initial working then people are more likely to answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a non-Taylor way using

- $\frac{t^\alpha}{e^t}\stackrel{t\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and
- $\frac{\log(1+t)}{t}\stackrel{t\to 0}{\longrightarrow}1$

$$\left(x-\sqrt{x-1}\log\left(x^2+e^{\sqrt x}\right)\right) = x-\sqrt{x-1}\log\left(e^{\sqrt x}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{e^{\sqrt x}}\right)\right)$$
$$= x- \sqrt{x-1}\left(\sqrt{x} + \log\left(1+\frac{x^2}{e^{\sqrt x}}\right)\right) = x-\sqrt{x^2-x} - \sqrt{x-1}\log\left(1+\underbrace{\frac{x^2}{e^{\sqrt x}}}_{\stackrel{x\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}0}\right)$$
$$= \underbrace{\frac{x}{x + \sqrt{x^2-x}}}_{\stackrel{x\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}\frac 12}- \underbrace{\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{x^2}{e^{\sqrt x}}\right)}{\frac{x^2}{e^{\sqrt x}}}}_{\stackrel{x\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}1}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{\sqrt{x-1}x^2}{e^{\sqrt x}}}_{\stackrel{x\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}0} \stackrel{x\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}\frac 12$$

Comment: Nice proof for sure !

Comment: +1 for smart use of standard limits.

Comment: thank you for the nice comments and the upvotes :-)

Answer (score 2):

You wrote *without Taylor series* but you did not forbid to compute !

Let $x=10^k$ and get the following results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & \text{value} \\
 3 & 0.50012447884491451460 \\
 4 & 0.50001250062503906523 \\
 5 & 0.50000125000625003906 \\
 6 & 0.50000012500006250004 \\
 7 & 0.50000001250000062500 \\
 8 & 0.50000000125000000625 \\
 9 & 0.50000000012500000006 \\
 10 & 0.50000000001250000000 \\
 11 & 0.50000000000125000000 \\
 12 & 0.50000000000012500000 \\
 13 & 0.50000000000001250000 \\
 14 & 0.50000000000000125000 \\
 15 & 0.50000000000000012500 \\
 16 & 0.50000000000000001250 \\
 17 & 0.50000000000000000125 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Nice pattern !

Comment: My bad, I thought that ban was obvious

Comment: @Mathi. You did not !

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x-\sqrt{x-1}\log\left(x^2+e^{\sqrt x}\right)\right) \\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x-\sqrt{x-1}\log\left( \Bigl(\frac{x^2}{e^{\sqrt x}}+1 \Bigr) e^{\sqrt x}\right)\right) \\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x-\sqrt{x-1}\log\left( e^{\sqrt x}\right)\right)
\end{align}
The above is done with the usual "backwards" logic. We shall continue to do so, since all the limits and the equations can be pushed backwards from.
\begin{align}
&= \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x-\sqrt{x-1}\sqrt x\right) \\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{ \bigl( x-\sqrt{x-1}\sqrt x\bigr)\bigl( x +\sqrt{x-1}\sqrt x\bigr)}{x+\sqrt{x-1}\sqrt x} \\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{ x^2-(x^2 - x)}{x+\sqrt{x-1}\sqrt x} \\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{ x}{x+\sqrt{x-1}\sqrt x} \\
&= \frac12
\end{align}

Comment: Oops I didn't notice an answer was already posted and accepted. Three minutes too slow.